How to make immutability a default behaviour with C preprocessor
I think that the benefits of data immutability outweigh the inconvenience of the implicit mut qualifier. That's why in my opinion it should be the default. I know that some functional languages implement types like this and Rust also does that.
The problem is, I can't figure out how to use C preprocessor to achive that. Specifically, I'd like do these replacements:
typename     -> typename const
typename_mut -> typename

I tried using naive defines:
#define int const int
#define int_mut int

However, this makes everything const. Swapping position changes nothing. How else could I approach that?
Update (additional info)
Naive version:
#define char const char
#define char_mut char

int main() {
    char_mut integer = 5;
    integer = 6;
}

expands to:
// gcc -E main.c
// # 0 "main.c"
// # 0 "<built-in>"
// # 0 "<command-line>"
// # 1 "main.c"

int main() {
    const char integer = 5;
    integer = 6;
}


One thing you could do is typedef an alternate name for int, e.g. typedef int my_int;  Then you could #define int_mut my_int.  Or you could just typedef int int_mut before defining your int macro.  But no matter how you do it, you'll need to be very careful to include any system header files before defining your int macro.  And if any of those header files define macros that reference int, then you'll be out of luck if you want to use those macros.

Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try it out.

@TomKarzes, your suggestion does work, but now int and int_mut are highlighted differently (as a macro and as a typedef accordingly). Now it indicates mutability, I guess) You should consider creating an answer for me to mark it as correct.

Well, I view it as a sort of half-baked suggestion.  It may solve the immediate problem, but I suspect doing something like this will be likely to cause problems down the road.  Redefining something as fundamental as int is very much fighting the language.  For instance, suppose you have two header files of your own that depend on this, and suppose they each want to include a standard header file.  It won't work, since int will be redefined before at least one of them is included.

Fair point. Maybe it makes sense to make a second header file where we undef all the defines. It won't remove the typedefs tho

Don't. #undef is unlucky, especially in header files. It always creates risk of unpredictable behaviour.

That would probably work.  The typedefs should be safe as long as you use names that don't conflict with anything.  But yeah, you'd want to #undef the macros for the builtin types, the redefine them (if needed) after the last standard include.  But it would still fail if, for instance, some standard macro like getchar() used int, at least if you tried to use it after defining your int macro.  My advice is to live with the default types, and make your own types if you want different behavior.

@yurich - Fighting the language is a fight you will just lose, and there are no winners. Lots of people have tried #define begin { and #define end } to make C look like their "old" language. It never works! The solution is to just learn to type const char and const int, and go with the flow. If nothing else, consider the poor readers of your code, who otherwise have to learn a different language - your C.

got it, but I know C pretty well and have experience with other languages, I don't have a problem adapting to syntax. I just wanted to know if such thing would even be possible with c, because usually it isn't, as most languages either dont have a preprocessor at all or it's really limited.

Defining keywords as macros is a bad idea.  You can't safely include any system header when any keywords are defined as a macro.  Consider using a prefix or suffix for both types: typedef const int c_int; typedef /* mutable */ int m_int;.

I tried using the keywords as macros. You were right, it backfired a little, for example, bool now causes "redefined warning", I'm sure there would be more if I continue. I mean, I could try to avoid it, but it's just not worth it at that point.
